# StorCLI: storcli show and "Hlth: Opt": how exhaustive is this?

Tags: hardware-raid, lsi, megaraid, storcli

I'm working on a script using StorCLI (Ver 1.21.06).

When I run:

```
./storcli show
```

I get (abbreviated):

```
Status Code = 0
Status = Success
```

As well as:

```
Hlth: 
Opt
```

Q1. I'm curious to know what the Status/Status code actually means: does this have anything to do with the status of the controller or just that the command executed successfully?

Q2: how exhaustive is the "./storcli show" command?  i.e. is the "Hlth: Opt" result including physical disk health or just controller health (battery, etc.)?

The reference manual is pretty terse, with only the following description of the `show` command as follows:

> storcli show
>
> This command shows a summary of controller and controller-associated information for the system. The summary
>   includes the number of controllers, the host name, the operating system information, and the overview of
>   existing configuration.

### EDIT

I'm looking for a means to monitor an LSI RAID array on a Lenovo TD340 server running ESXi (free version). Server has an IMM (first gen), which has no visibility into the LSI RAID card installed.

MegaRAID is unreliable, as the discovery/querying takes an excess of 30 minutes to finish "finding" the ESXi server, which then results in another undocumented amount of time (exceeding an hour) for it to finish logging in (where you're in limbo wondering if the greyed out "Login" button actually did anything).

I simply don't trust MegaRAID Manager at this point to have stable enough visibility into the ESXi host/LSI RAID status to be a reliable means of monitoring.

So StorCLI works natively on ESXi, where I'm going to write a script to run `storcli show` (ideally) and parse the output, and writing to a log and sending an alert.

Comment: For what purpose are you using `storcli`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @030 I added more information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is now a little bit muddled, but check this out:

https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Storage-Systems/RAID-Controllers/LSI-Hardware-RAID--2D-S-2EM-2EA-2ER-2ET-Monitoring/details

Seems to do what you are wanting to do. And, no, you don't actually have to run Nagios to run this script and make your own alerting superstructure. However, Nagios (well, I like Icinga) is damn good for its purpose. :)

Answer (score 2):

The status code and status lines return the result of the command that was ran.  This information is returned from pretty much every command that you can run, and it wouldn't make sense for every command to return controller status.

The show command will return basic information about the controller and arrays, and it will not show optimal if there are any issues with the drives.  You may want to look into using the show all command in your script, as it will return information on the drives as well as the arrays themselves.  This will let you see if a drive is offline or missing, rather than just that there is an issue with the array.

The official LSI documentation PDF can be downloaded [here](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12352476).